# topic_tools transform works in console but not in launch file

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I'm still quite new to ROS, and is getting stuck at something that is most likely a syntax error. I have a `/imu` topic, and I want to send the `imu.orientation.y` into a `pid`. I cannot `remap` the `pid` to look at the imu's `y` field. Therefore, I want to use `topic_tools transform` function. I can get it to work by typing it into the console, but when I attempt to put it in a launch file the 'transform' dies immediately.

I created a minimal example showing the case where it works, and where it doesn't.

---

**Working example using console**

For this case I run the following launch file

```
<launch>
    <node name="pub" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" args="pub /foo std_msgs/Float64 0.5 -r 1" />
</launch>
```

and then run the following command to start the transform node:

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /foo /bar std_msgs/Float64 'm'
```

To prove this works I ran the command `rostopic echo \bar` and the value `0.5` is printed once per second as expected.

---

**Broken example using launch file**

I run the following launch file

```
<launch>
    <node name="pub" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" args="pub /foo std_msgs/Float64 0.5 -r 1" />
    <node name="foobar" pkg="topic_tools" type="transform" args="/foo /bar std_msgs/Float64 'm'"/>
</launch>
```

This then throws an error upon launching showing that the `foobar` node died:

```
... logging to /home/hein/.ros/log/97930396-806f-11ea-85fc-84c5a6fcae4a/roslaunch-hein-Latitude-5500-4511.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://hein-Latitude-5500:39487/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.5

NODES
  /
    foobar (topic_tools/transform)
    pub (rostopic/rostopic)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4522]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 97930396-806f-11ea-85fc-84c5a6fcae4a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4533]
started core service [/rosout]
process[pub-2]: started with pid [4536]
process[foobar-3]: started with pid [4537]
ERROR: Wrong input topic (or topic field): /foo
[foobar-3] process has died [pid 4537, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/topic_tools/transform /foo /bar std_msgs/Float64 m __name:=foobar __log:=/home/hein/.ros/log/97930396-806f-11ea-85fc-84c5a6fcae4a/foobar-3.log].
log file: /home/hein/.ros/log/97930396-806f-11ea-85fc-84c5a6fcae4a/foobar-3*.log
```

Looking at the log file shows the following:

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,485: init_node, name[/foobar], pid[2211]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,485: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,486: Started XML-RPC server [http://hein-Latitude-5500:37033/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,486: ROS Slave URI: [http://hein-Latitude-5500:37033/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,486: _ready: http://hein-Latitude-5500:37033/
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,486: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,486: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.init][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,586: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,586: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,588: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,588: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rospy.core][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,610: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2020-04-16 19:49:16,611: atexit
```

---

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? I tried removing the `'` around the `m` variable, but this didn't change anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349655/topic_tools-transform-works-in-console-but-not-in-launch-file/) by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-16**:
It's likely there are more lines to the error you show, as what we see here is only the summary (as in: the process exited unexpectedly). It'd be very helpful to see those additional lines.

**Comment by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on 2020-04-17**:
@gvdhoorn, now that you mention it, it does say `ERROR: Wrong input topic (or topic field): /foo`. Updated the question, and I will do some more research.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-17**:
Please post a *verbatim* copy-paste of the entire output that appears when you `roslaunch` your `.launch` file.

**Comment by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on 2020-04-17**:
Updated the question as per your request.

**Comment by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on 2020-04-17**:
It's most likely related to the transform namespace bug. [Link](https://answers.ros.org/question/232748/subscribe-one-variable-from-big-topic-msg/)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-17**:
Where are the namespaces in your example `.launch` files?

**Comment by [Hein Wessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/53262/hein-wessels/) on 2020-04-17**:
I didn't define any namespaces. What's shown in the question is the complete `.launch` file. Could that be a problem?

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-14**:
what is the solution?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-11**:
I can duplicate this but only with a fresh roscore- the first time I run the launch it fails, but relaunching works fine on a second and third attempt.  Doing a `rosnode cleanup` and `rosparam delete /` doesn't replicate the fresh roscore, it continues to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a race condition that fails when roslaunching with a fresh roscore, but there is an option to avoid it `--wait_for_start`

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1942

(it's the same code in `relay_field` and `transform`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node name="pub" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" args="pub /foo std_msgs/Float64 0.5 -r 1" />
  <node name="foobar" pkg="topic_tools" type="transform" args="/foo /bar std_msgs/Float64 'm' --wait-for-start"/>
</launch>
```

That option really ought to be true by default.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2021-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1